# Type a generated record of functions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to generate a record of functions that will apply to a list of function an other function. (Composition of function)

For that I use a reduce but I am not able to type correctly the arguments, I got the following error:

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter
```

This is my testcase:

```js
const funcA = (n: number) => `${n}`
const funcB = (s: string) => s.length

// Cannot do this with a reduce
const functions = [funcA, funcB]
const exported = functions.reduce((acc, func) => ({
   ...acc,
    // Args type is args: [s: string] | [n: number]
   [func.name]: (...args: Parameters<typeof func>) => setTimeout(() => func(...args), 100)
}), {})


// Expected output
const recordOfFunctions = {
  funcA:  (...args: Parameters<typeof funcA>) => setTimeout(() => funcA(...args), 100),
  funcB:  (...args: Parameters<typeof funcB>) => setTimeout(() => funcB(...args), 100),
}
```

Any idea on how to type it correctly ?

Thanks :)

Comment: For one thing... arrow functions don't have names... So even if I did do some black magicks here it wouldn't work at runtime. Might want to address that first.

Comment: Welp, I stand corrected; arrow functions *do* have names if they are assigned to a variable.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/w8L30w) is a potential workaround. You *could* use an array but then you'd have to explicitly pass the keys again. Also, some sort of cast is necessary with this kind of remapping.